# In Al27 (alpha,n): why is a neutron ejected?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, neutrons, particle-accelerators

Why does a neutron get ejected when Aluminium-27 is hit with an alpha particle?

It seems like:
Al-27 + He-4 --> P-31 (stable) and a gamma/(s) as the nucleus re-arranges. So why eject the neutron and go to the unstable P-30, which then decays by beta+ via:
Al-27 + He-4 --> P-30 + n?

If it helps, this is the context of 6MeV alphas being accelerated at a fixed target, but I guess my question is more the general why eject a neutron and make the unstable isotope? Is this to do with the neutron being pushed out by forward momentum?

Comment: https://www.osti.gov/etdeweb/servlets/purl/20644453 may help. The point is, the 27Al + $\alpha$ makes an excited nucleus and one possible route out is ejecting a neutron. Whether the 30P is stable by itself or not is irrelevant, it is just that 30P+n is more stable than the excited 31P nucleus at that moment.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. So it's merely P-31* just losing energy by whatever means available, regardless of the product? 
What makes it prefer one path over another (which I guess is essentially why do the cross-sections differ?)
Thank you for the link, I shall check that out

Comment: There are multiple paths with different weights. It might release just a gamma. It might release a proton (and maybe a gamma) and become 30Si.

Comment: What should make 1 path more favourable than another? Energy loss?

Comment: Just different possible paths with different probabilities. Just like many unstable isotopes have multiple decay paths possible.

Comment: Okay, so no particular rhyme or reason as to why one is more likely? 'Just the way nature is' sort of thing?